# logback.xml appender not used with cats IOApp

Tags: scala, logback, scala-cats, logstash-logback-encoder, cats-effect

I have a scala app which uses the AWS Kinesis Client Library.

I am using logback with the logstash encoder to format the logs from my app and the KCL as JSON.

My App is also written using `cats.effects.IO`.

```
import cats.effects._

object Main extends App {

  run(args.toList).unsafeRunSync

  def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = { .. }

}
```

When the above code runs, logs from my app and from the KCL are correctly formatted through my JSON appender.

The problem arises when I try to use `cats.effects.IOApp`:

```
import cats.effects._

object Main extends IOApp {

  def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = { .. }

}
```

When this version runs, the logs from my app are still correctly formatted through my JSON appender, but the logs from the KCL revert back to the default basic logger.

I have narrowed this down to the use of `Fiber` under the hood, and can reproduce the problem if I use `run(args.toList).start.flatMap(_.join).unsafeRunSync` which is essentially what `IOApp` is doing under the hood. I am running on the JVM, so [this](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/blob/38c2995117bd8e65a337f56ca37d6508dbca67f8/core/jvm/src/main/scala/cats/effect/internals/IOAppPlatform.scala#L25) is the code that is running under the hood.

My `logback.xml`:

```
  <appender name="json" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
      <providers>
        <pattern>
          <pattern>
            {
              "level": "%level",
              "message": "%message"
            }
          </pattern>
        </pattern>
        <nestedField>
          <fieldName>properties</fieldName>
          <providers>
            <timestamp>
              <fieldName>utcTimestamp</fieldName>
              <pattern>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'</pattern>
              <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
            </timestamp>
            <arguments/>
          </providers>
        </nestedField>
        <stackTrace/>
      </providers>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="json" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relying on the auto discovery of the `logback.xml` when there are multiple conflicting dependencies on the class path means there is no guarantee as to which will load first.

Since there is already a dependency for:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "jcl-over-slf4j" % "1.7.21"
```

You just need to exclude the commons logger:

```
excludeDependencies += "commons-logging" % "commons-logging"
```

This way the KCL is forced to use the correct logger instead of having to choose.